# Android Custom online bank payment

Tags: android

I am developing an android application to feature payment through credit card,and online payment through bank account like paypal.

But i have an issue, i don't need to use paypal or other third party api to feature online payment.
Or can i customise paypal api to hide it's screen in my app.

Please anyone reply me if it is possible.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users will be a bit skeptical in paying if they don't recognize the payment gateway. Its always better to have a trusted payment gateway. You can always use Google merchant account for [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide paypal screen. and if you want to pay through card then use paypal MECL library.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide it's screen. Users will generally to not give money to some unknown payment system and it is better you use a recognized service like Paypal. When people are paying for stuff, they would want trusted services to handle their transactions.

Rather than Paypal, You can use [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html) provided by google. It's what all developers use.

Comment: Hi all thanks for your reply but is there any way to implement this feature because it's requirement of my app.